In VB.Net, RichTextBox will not adjust to text height when in Panel
Following a suggestion on this site to have a RichTextBox slowly scroll down automatically, I have a RichTextBox inside a panel.  The RichTextBox must have a height longer than the Panel to force the Panel's vertical scroll bar.  The scrolling is achieved with a timer -
Panel1.AutoScrollPosition = New Point(Panel1.AutoScrollPosition.X, Math.Abs(Panel1.AutoScrollPosition.Y) + 1)

This works perfectly.
But, if I load a text file with -
RTB1.Text = File.ReadAllText("C:\Users\User\Desktop\File.TXT")

The text file only loads to the height of RTB1, about a quarter of the file.  If I keep increasing the height, at say 100 000 it reverts to 65535, which I assume is some sort of maximum.  But this is not enough to load a 600KB Text file.
Outside of a panel RTB1 loads the same text file correctly to the end.
I have tried unsuccessfully various ways mentioned on this site to force it to load the full text file.  Most are old and seem not to be required as the the newer normal RTB loads correctly anyway. The suggested code is very long so I haven't included it.  It seems to be an issue with the Panel.
One suggestion was
RTB1.ClientSize = New Size(RTB1.ClientSize.Width, GetHeightOfFirstLines(RTB1, 11000))

But again, anything over 1100 in this code just doesn't do anything
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Yes, 65535 is the magic maximum for scrolling.  HIWORD is a 16-bit value.  Throw this away since it can't work.  Why RichTextBox.SelectionStart + ScrollToCaret() can't solve your problem is not clear from the question.  Don't put too much effort into a feature that users really detest, perhaps, nobody actually reads a 600K text file.

Many thanks for replying.  I'm not sure what's happening with the RTB.  Is the entire file loading but the last half of the file is not accessible because of the scrolling maximum, or is the file only loading to the height of the RTB?  Cant see how to establish this.
